# Datetime parse not working for specific format

Tags: c#

Hello experts i am not able to parse the datetime object  from following format

```
2019-12-04T04:26:29:00
```

in **c#**. When I trying to parse this format I'll get

```
04-12-2019 04:26:29
```

Without `T` as `DateTime` object

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome. Also, what country do you live in?

Comment: If you parse it you get a `DateTime` object, and they have no format. The date and time are simply stored as a `long` value (Ticks). The only time you see a format is when it's converted to a human-readable string representation.

Comment: `2019-12-04T04:26:29:00` won't parse by default (at least not with the default culture settings). Replace the last `: with `.` and it'll work. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8 for the formats accepted by default. Or you can use [parseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) and specify your own custom input format. As for the _output_, that's an entirely separate issue. The DateTime object doesn't store it in any text format, but you can output it however you wish

Comment: `DateTime` is a `struct` (i.e. a set of properties like `Year`, `Month` etc.) it doesn't have any default string representation. If you want to represent given `DateTime` as a `string` use *formatting*: `string result = myDateTime.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy'T'HH:mm.ss");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToString() function in the following way to format your DateTime:

```
DateTime yourDateTime = ...//your DateTime value
yourDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")//or any other format
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse user input like this:

```
DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse(enteredString);
```

If you have a specific format for the string, you should use the other method:

```
DateTime loadedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(loadedString, "d", null);
```

"d" stands for the short date pattern ([see MSDN for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)) and null specifies that the current culture should be used for parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last 2 zeros and try.

Your code is

```
2019-12-04T04:26:29:00
```

The suggested code change is

```
2019-12-04T04:26:29
```